# How do I modify a mesh after it has been created in bevy rust?

Tags: rust, rendering, game-development, bevy

I am working on a procedural generation system and want to be able to modify a mesh frame by frame in bevy rust.

I have tried using `assets.get_mut()` however this results in an error: `` help: trait `DerefMut` is required to modify through a dereference, but it is not implemented for `bevy::prelude::Res<'_, bevy::prelude::Assets<bevy::prelude::Mesh>> ``

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is what my current code looks like roughly:

```rust
// Function which is executed at the very start

fn setup (
    mut commands: Commands,
    mut meshes: ResMut<Assets<Mesh>>,
    mut materials: ResMut<Assets<StandardMaterial>>,
    asset_server: Res<AssetServer>
) {

    let mut mesh = Mesh::from(bevy::prelude::shape::Icosphere { radius: 0.5, subdivisions: 10 });

    commands.spawn()
            .insert_bundle(PbrBundle {
                mesh: meshes.add(mesh),
                material: materials.add(colour.into()),
                ..Default::default()
            })
            .insert(Transform::from_xyz(0.0, 0.0, 0.0));
}

// Function which is executed every frame

fn update_planets (
    mut query: Query<(&Transform, &Handle<Mesh>)>,
    assets: Res<Assets<Mesh>>
) {

    let (transform, handle) = query.get_single_mut().expect("");
    let mut mesh = assets.get_mut(handle.id); // Error caused here
    if mesh.is_some() {
        let positions = temp.attribute(Mesh::ATTRIBUTE_POSITION).unwrap();
        if let VertexAttributeValues::Float32x3(thing) = positions {
            let mut temporary = Vec::new();
            for i in thingy {
                let temp = Vec3::new(i[0], i[1], i[2]);
                ... // Modify temp here
                temporary.push(temp);
            }

            mesh.unwrap().insert_attribute(Mesh::ATTRIBUTE_POSITION, temporary);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show a small example with code so we can help you more easily?

Answer (score 5):

Fairly new to Bevy, but if you want to mutate an asset, I believe you should be using `ResMut` rather than `Res`.

i.e. `assets: Res<Assets<Mesh>>` should actually be `mut assets: ResMut<Assets<Mesh>>`.